# Using Laravel View Composer class

Tags: php

I have created the class composer, please where can i register it on the application is it the global.php or where

```
class UserComposer
{
    public function __construct(Sentry $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function currentUser()
    {
        return $this->user->getUser();
    }
    public function compose($view)
    {
        $view->with('name', $this->currentUser()->first_name);
    }
}
```

please where will i registered it?

Comment: global.php should be fine. There are a number of spots you could hook into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you could do this

### 1. Using your start files

you could register it in app/start/global.php

From the laravel docs

> Your application's start files are stored at app/start. By default, three are included with > your application: global.php, local.php, and artisan.php.

But I prefer using the global.php for including other files so as not to populate the global.php

In this context (registering view composers), you could create a file 'app/composers.php' and include it in your global.php file like so:

```
require app_path() . '/composers.php';
```

### 2. Using Service Providers

Create a service Provider. (Sample code below)

```
class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerUserComposer();
    }

    protected function registerUserComposers()
    {
        $this->app['view']->composers([
            'UserComposer@currentUser' => [
                'view1', 'view2'
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then add an entry into the 'providers' array of your app/config/app.php

```
'providers' => array(
    ....

    'ComposerServiceProvider'
)
```